# In MySQL, what do I put inside my.cnf so that all tables are UTF-8 that works with emojis by default?

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like every table and database (to be created) to be utf-8 that works with emojis.  I understand that there are a few variables I need to define inside `my.cnf`:

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = ??? '
init_connect='SET NAMES ???'
character-set-server = ???
collation-server = ???
```

However, I'm not sure what to put in the `???`.  What do I put inside `my.cnf`?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

May be you need to define these options as well:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

Hope it helps. Cheers

Update: Changed to utf8mb4

Comment: utf8 doesn't work with emojis. Only utf8mb4 does.

Comment: changed it to utf8mb4 ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this site https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Although Jim's answer should also work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SF. Please don't provide link only answers.